# Leetcode #377 Combination Sum IV, Unexpected Behavior In My Code

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, backtracking

I was in the middle of doing this problem found at:
https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/

Here's my code:

```
class Solution:
def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:

    length = len(nums)
    count = 0 
    tracker = []
    result = []

    def backtrack(targetLeft: int) -> None:
        nonlocal count

        if targetLeft == 0:
            print(tracker)
            result.append(tracker)
            count += 1
            return

        elif targetLeft > 0:
            for number in nums:
                if targetLeft - number < 0:
                    continue
                tracker.append(number)
                backtrack(targetLeft - number)
                tracker.pop()

        return


    backtrack(target)
    print(result)
    return count
```

In the process of understanding my code, I was trying to print out the list of combinations leading to the target sum. I also print the result array at the end, which stores all the combinations. When the code is run, this is the stdout:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1] 
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 1]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

It seems to generate the correct combinations, however these combinations are not being appended correctly to the result array. The result array comes back to an array of empty arrays. I tried going through the code by hand, but I am not too sure what is causing this to happen.

Comment: its possibly because you are appending a reference to a list to your result list, but as you iterate you pop from this temporary list, resulting you in removing items from the result lists also.

Comment: Try if result.append(tracker.copy()) helps

Comment: That makes so much sense, that worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a simple linear solution O(N), where N -- is the sum you're trying to reach. The point is, you don't have to generate all combinations to count them.

1. count how many ways are to reach N=1 (answer: 1, because obvious)
2. count how many ways are to reach N=2 (answer: 2, one from N=1, one from zero pos)
3. count how many ways are to reach N=3, 4, 5, 6 and so on, based on your previous results, basically sum up the results for N-1, N-2 and all these numbers you have.
4. profit!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, nums, target, memo):
            if target in memo:
               return memo[target]

            if target==0:
                return 1
            if target<0:
                return 0 
            count=0
            for num in nums: 
                remainder=target-num
                count += self.solve(nums,remainder,memo)

            memo[target]=count
            return count

     def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
         # Calling the function
         return self.solve(nums, target, {})
```

Try this code using Python 3 format at Leetcode you will pass...